# Display Lookup Field of a object in LWC lightning-record-form

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

I am able to display all the User related field in lightning-record-form in LWC, except Lookup fields like Profile, UserRole.

```
<lightning-record-formobject-api-name="User" fields={userCreationFields} columns="2" mode="edit" onsubmit={handleSubmit}></lightning-record-form>
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation) `lightning-record-form` is limited to SObjects supported by User Interface API. See [UI API Supported Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started_supported_objects.htm) article.

Unfortunately only workaround is to build your own lookup input and moving away from `lightning-record-form` to something more flexible (i.e. `lightning-record-edit-form`).

You can find plenty examples of custom lookups throughout internet ([this one](https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-lookup-lwc) looks fine). Good luck!